# Defining Angular Service and Controllers - Data not persisting between views

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, service, controller, persistence

I want to keep my Angular Controllers and Services separated.

Current paths:

```
project/client/js/controllers/product-controller.js

project/client/js/services/editProduct-service.js
```

Please see the following gist for code:

https://gist.github.com/astemborskim/4673d024d5a78347fae8

My initial question is should I have to add a source to my html that identifies the service. I was under the impression that you only need to define the controller in the HTML view.

My understanding is that my app.js is defined as:

```
var app = angular.module('warehouseApp', ['ngResource']);
```

my controllers are then defined using **app**.controller and services as **app**.service.

I should be able to do this becuase in my inital html view (jade layout) app.js is defined as a src for all my views:

script( text='text/javascript' src="/app.js")

```
docutype 
html(ng-app='warehouseApp')
    head
        script( src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js")
        script( src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-resource.js")
        script( text='text/javascript' src="/app.js")
        link( rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="Screen")
        link( rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        title Acme Warehouse - #{title}
        block navigation
    body.container-fluid
        div
            block heading
            block content
    footer
        block footer
```

However my service, even though I believe it is reference properly in my controller, will not work unless i include the service/factory in the same file or I reference the service in my view as a src.

Example:

```
script(text="text/javascript", src="../js/controllers/test-controller.js")
script(text="text/javascript", src="../js/services/editProduct-service.js")
```

CONTROLLER 1:

```
app.controller('productController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'editProductService', function ($scope, $resource, editProductService) { 

    $scope.setEditProduct = function (product){

    editProductService.saveProductForEdit(product);
    console.log(product);

}


}]);
```

CONTROLLER 2:

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'editProductService', 
function ($scope, $resource, editProductService) {

    $scope.editProd={};

    $scope.getEditProduct = function (){

    $scope.editProd = editProductService.getProductForEdit();
    console.log($scope.editProd);
}


}]);
```

The main issue is that I don't have persistant data between my 2 controllers. The data object I set in my services through controller 1 is undefined in controller 2.  I believe that this is due to the fact that I am calling the service in my html as a source. When the view is loaded it is redefining my service variables back to an empty object.

Do you concur?

What is the proper way to inject my service into the controllers?  Shouldn't they be able to reference each other via the the shared app variable in my app.js?

I'm trying to make form data in one view show up in another form on another view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to save your state in the service itself just use the reference in the controller. Also, you always need to reference the source of any js code that you want to use. Using angular doesn't make that an exception.

Comment: Is this a single page app or is the server actually sending a new page each time you click a link?  If you get a complete new page then all state is going to be lost.

Comment: New page. If that is the case, then I misunderstood how the service worked. I thought it assisted in persisting data. If that is the case, what is the best way to pass an object for use between separate views. I grab a "product" object via search on one page. My goal is bring that object with me to another view so it can be edited by the user.

Comment: This has nothing to do with services and angular.  When you reload the page everything starts from ground zero.  Take a look at angular-routing.  This lets you switch pages internally within the browser.  You will have url's like /#/home instead of /home.  I'd suggest making a few simple angularjs apps without the jade stuff in order to understand what is happening.